# Python Movie.py - How do I handle(deallocate/close) no longer used clips?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, contextmanager, moviepy

## Expected

> 1. Create ImageClips of varying duration and append to:
>      `clips = []` *(line 13-16)*
> 2. Make ImageClips into a concatenated clip:
>      `concatenated_videoclips(clips, method="chain")` *(line 19)*
> 3. Add Audio to concatenated clip *(line 20-21)*
> 4. Loops through image-file list and remove them from memory *(not in code example)*
> 5. Loop through list of `clips = [<ImageClip>]` and close each clip then delete from list *(line 24-29)*
> 6. Return concatenated clip *(line 32)* and append to another list in global scope *(not in code example)*
> 7. Repeat steps 1-6
> 8. Concatenate all clips that were added to global list then `set_audio(background_music_path.mp3)` *(not in code example)*
> 9. New Video written to `new_video_path.mp4` *(not in code example)*
>      Blockquote

## Actual

> - 5% of the time goes through process outputting video correctly
> - 95% of the time will crash due to **killed: 9** or **leaked semaphore error**
> - Tends to reach 120GB in activity monitor by end of process until Python venv terminated
> - Using *Tracemalloc module* it shows linearly increasing memory usage when:
>
>   - Adding new *ImageClips* related to:
>
>     1. *imageio/plugins/pillow.py* (imageio Pillow python wrapper)
>     2. *moviepy/video/VideoClip.py* (from `class ImageClip(VideoClip):`)
>   - concatenating `clips` list of *ImageClips*:
>
>     3. *numpy/lib/shape_base.py*

### Memory Usage by `Tracemalloc`

#### Immediately after first ImageClips Created:

```
#1
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py:900: 293626.7 KiB
1.0 * img[:, :, 3] / 255, ismask=True)
#2
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageio/plugins/pillow.py:792: 146813.8 KiB
frame = np.array(frame, dtype=dtype)
```

#### After first ImageClips are concatenated together:

```
#1
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py:900: 293626.7 KiB
 1.0 * img[:, :, 3] / 255, ismask=True)
#2
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py:1256: 234900.2 KiB
 c = c.reshape(-1, n).repeat(nrep, 0)
#3
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageio/plugins/pillow.py:792: 146813.8 KiB
frame = np.array(frame, dtype=dtype)
```

#### After several iterations of concatenating ImageClips:

```
#1
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py:900: 32709961.1 KiB
 1.0 * img[:, :, 3] / 255, ismask=True)
#2
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageio/plugins/pillow.py:792: 16355008.3 KiB
 c = c.reshape(-1, n).repeat(nrep, 0)
#3
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py:1256: 6107405.9 KiB
frame = np.array(frame, dtype=dtype)
```

### CODE EXAMPLE

```
1  import random
2
3  # Moviepy library
4  from moviepy.editor import concatenate_videoclips
5  from moviepy.video.VideoClip import ImageClip
6  from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
7
8  def make_movie(img_files):
9     # List to hold all of the ImageClips
10    clips = []
11
12    # Loop through the image files and create ImageClip with random duration
13    for img in img_files:
14      duration = random.randomint(0,3)
15      with ImageClip(img, duration=duration) as img_clip:
16        clips.append(img_clip)
17
18    # Concatenate all of ImageClips in clips and save to all_clips (audio for example sake)
19    with concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="chain") as all_clips:
20      with AudioFileClip(audio_file_path.mp3) as audio_clip:
21        all_clips = all_clips.set_audio(audio_clip)
22
23    # Loop through list of clips and close individually 
24    for used_clip in clips:
25      used_clip.close()
26    
27    # Delete all clips in list
28    while len(clips) > 0:
29      del clips[0]
30    
31    # Return concatenated clip 'all_clips'
32    return all_clips
33
34
```

## End Result

- After returned, all_clips will be added to a list that will eventually be concatenated once more to create a final video clip
- The problem is that the program no longer needs all of the ImageClips once used and it has proven difficult deallocating them from memory

#### System Setup

- macOS
- MoviePy 1.0.2

> Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's threading or multiprocessing library. Run each call to `make_movie()` inside a different process, and the memory should be freed when the function finishes. You could also write each individual `all_clips` to disk using `all_clips.write_videofile()` and read them all in again at the end when you want to create the final video.

Let me know if you have more problems.